# Oyster mushrooms turn reddish brown, pretty much every time. Is this a moisture or temperature or some other problem? Pls help

Tags: growth, fungus, mushrooms, dryness, growing-medium

This is my 6th or 7th batch of mushrooms, and they all eventually turn the same kind of reddish brown and the caps don't really form.

I've managed to get a couple of good flushes, but something is clearly wrong and I can't seem to get the moisture or temperature part right (despite trying damn near every level of misting, light, and environment my tiny little apartment affords :) Even the brown parts are still moist so I suspect it's not a matter of drying out, but who knows.

Hopefully someone here can take a look at the images below and say "Duh... you're just not doing X". (But even if not, any advice on the right level of misting and what causes the reddish brown to form is helpful.)

Thanks so much!

[image: Mushroom bag 3]
[image: Mushroom bag 2]
[image: Mushroom bag 1]

Comment: None of them look like any oyster mushrooms I have seen/found in the woods..

Answer (score 1):

I have seen them grow like this - so disappointing when they start to fruit and stop. Rather than mist a lot, just put a clear bag over the whole thing to keep the humidity high, and have a little water available at the base.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Bagged the blocks. Do you think the brown bits can come back to life or should I take them off and discard them?

Comment: I have only had them fruiting a few times so I couldn't say. When I saw the dark brown, and no growth for a few days, they never grew further. Good luck.